# Apple iCloud CalDAV '403 Forbidden' when creating event

Tags: calendar, http-status-code-403, caldav

This is similar to [403 CalDAV error: valid-calendar-object-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757506/403-caldav-error-valid-calendar-object-resource/47452590#47452590) except that the trivial solution (adding the UID to the URL) was already implemented. I'm receiving '403 Forbidden' from the iCloud CalDAV server for one specific user account. I can pull the list of calendars and the events on the calendars, but can't create or modify events.

Here's a working example:

```
$ curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/calendar" -u "user.x@email.com:zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz" --data-binary @- https://p34-caldav.icloud.com/xxxxxxxxxx/calendars/{calendarId1}/working-event-1.ics  <<EOF
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> VERSION:2.0
> BEGIN:VEVENT
> DTSTAMP:20180827T204058Z
> UID:working-event-1
> SUMMARY:Test
> DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20180812
> DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20180813
> LOCATION:
> DESCRIPTION:
> LAST-MODIFIED:20180827T204058Z
> END:VEVENT
> END:VCALENDAR
> EOF
*   Trying 17.248.142.21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to p34-caldav.icloud.com (17.248.142.21) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.icloud.com
* Server certificate: Apple IST CA 2 - G1
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user.x@email.com'
> PUT /xxxxxxxxx/calendars/{calendarId1}/working-event-1.ics HTTP/1.1
> Host: p34-caldav.icloud.com
> Authorization: Basic <redacted>
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/calendar
> Content-Length: 252
>
* upload completely sent off: 252 out of 252 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: AppleHttpServer/2f080fc0
< Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 14:00:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-auto-schedule, calendar-audit, caldavserver-supports-telephone, calendar-managed-attachments, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-subscribed, calendarserver-home-sync
< X-Responding-Server: caldav:33400701:mr22p34ic-ztbu09061801:8001:1815B22:86058e50c4
< X-Transaction-Id: 5c2aa4be-7b79-4bd0-a6d8-39dd2ec7b4b1
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< via: icloudedge:ch41p00ic-zteu03153301:7401:18RC398:Chicago
< X-Apple-Request-UUID: 5c2aa4be-7b79-4bd0-a6d8-39dd2ec7b4b1
< access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
< access-control-expose-headers: Via
<
* Connection #0 to host p34-caldav.icloud.com left intact
```

I receive '201 Created' and DAV headers as expected

Here's a non-working example (a different account):

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/calendar" -u "user.y@email.com:zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz" --data-binary @- https://p53-caldav.icloud.com/yyyyyyyyy/calendars/{calendarId2}/not-working-event-1.ics  <<EOF
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> VERSION:2.0
> BEGIN:VEVENT
> DTSTAMP:20180827T204058Z
> UID:not-working-event-1
> SUMMARY:Test
> DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20180812
> DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20180813
> LOCATION:
> DESCRIPTION:
> LAST-MODIFIED:20180827T204058Z
> END:VEVENT
> END:VCALENDAR
> EOF
*   Trying 17.248.142.18...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to p53-caldav.icloud.com (17.248.142.18) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.icloud.com
* Server certificate: Apple IST CA 2 - G1
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user.y@email.com'
> PUT /yyyyyyyyy/calendars/{calendarId2}/not-working-event-1.ics HTTP/1.1
> Host: p53-caldav.icloud.com
> Authorization: Basic <redacted>
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:text/calendar
> Content-Length: 256
>
* upload completely sent off: 256 out of 256 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: AppleHttpServer/2f080fc0
< Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 14:01:18 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Apple-Jingle-Correlation-Key: S4UK6BYWHBHAHPOFOJX7APFQXU
< apple-seq: 0
< apple-tk: false
< Apple-Originating-System: UnknownOriginatingSystem
< X-Responding-Instance: caldavj:45301001:pv43p53ic-zteg03082001:8501:1815B46:de9f14897
< X-Apple-API-Version: v1
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< via: icloudedge:ch41p00ic-zteu03152101:7401:18RC398:Chicago
< X-Apple-Request-UUID: 9728af07-1638-4e03-bdc5-726ff03cb0bd
< access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID
< access-control-expose-headers: Via
<
* Connection #0 to host p53-caldav.icloud.com left intact
```

I receive '403 Forbidden', no 'DAV' header, and a couple new headers. The user says they are able to use their iCal apps as normal, and they appear to have write access to the calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, in the last few days, this became an issue with seemingly *all* Apple accounts. Evidently, Apple's servers are now requiring the PRODID field on the VCALENDAR object...like so:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//MyProductId//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180827T204058Z
UID:not-working-event-1
SUMMARY:Test
DTSTART;TZID=America/Chicago:20180812
DTEND;TZID=America/Chicago:20180813
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20180827T204058Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously it was affecting some accounts only but from last two days it gave error for everyone and following solution worked for me -:

I was already using PRODID. I am using ical.net library for ics creation and on setting status as confirmed it creates ics with text having "STATUS:Confirmed" in it for create event, by changing manually "STATUS:Confirmed" to "STATUS:CONFIRMED" it worked.

You can also upgrade ical.net to latest, it will also work. But I am facing some issues with it so I stick to this solution until I get it resolved.